# How to use sforce.one.navigateToURL on VF page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I created one Action Button(Action Type = VF page) on opportunity. This Action Button should redirect to Opportunity Edit page (I don't want to use Standard one). But the below one is always redirecting to Blank page.

**VF page :**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="true" id="vfpage" >
<script type="text/javascript">
         sforce.one.navigateToURL('one/one.app#/sObject/'+OpportunityId+'/e?=');
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redirecting to a null value (OpportunityId is not defined). However, you should not create a link like this anyways; instead, use [editRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm):

```
// Merge opportunity Id into a string, then redirect via navigateToSObject
sforce.one.editRecord('{!Opportunity.Id}');
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to redirect to Edit page not detail page. When I add something like this sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!Opportunity.Id}/e?='); it is again showing blank page

Comment: To extend, mr. fox’s answer; always look at documentation, there is also a [editRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) for navigating to edit screen.

Comment: @Learner I went ahead and updated the answer to reflect the link from Rahul. You need to read the documentation to figure out the appropriate method to use. navigateToURL is only for navigating to external URLs or those not reachable by one of the other methods.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am sorry I will keep in mind next time. Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: this documentation seems broken, 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

i need to find a way to call standard edit page in javascript